# hsdis Windows Compilation Failure - C compiler cannot create executables - Error 77, Error 2

Tags: java, linux, makefile

I am attempting to build hsdis for use on Windows. I first tried using Cygwin via the following command:

`make ARCH=amd64 BINUTILS=binutils-2.26 MINGW=x86_64-w64-mingw32`

And receive [this](https://pastebin.com/EjnGictZ) log file with errors beginning at line 103.

I then attempted to use the MinGW64 cross-compiler (as outlined [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/CrossQuickstart/)) on a Linux VM with the following command:

`make ARCH=amd64 MINGW=x86-64-w64-mingw32 BINUTILS=binutils-2.26`

However, the result was [this](https://pastebin.com/wFzu2ECj) log file and no built DLL.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, and I would be more than happy to provide any additional information. Thank you!

Comment: Where's the java in this question?

Comment: hsdis is utilized to view the assembly instructions in Java programs